# I want to call an object method from a function that has been passed as an argument to the object constructor

Tags: android, function, kotlin, methods, arguments

I have this block of code where I want to call a method of `NavDrawerItemAdapter` from the function of `ItemSelectedListener`.

Is there a way that I can do that?

```
private fun setupNavDrawer() {
        binding.aMainNavDrawerI.iNavDrawerListNavDrawerItemsRv.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = NavDrawerItemAdapter(NavDrawerItemAdapter.ItemSelectedListener {
                
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That pretty much depends on whether the `ItemSelectedListener` lambda receives the adapter as argument (can't tell from your code).

For example, if this(or similar) where the definition of the listener class:

```
class ItemSelectedListener(function: (NavDrawerItemAdapter) -> Unit) {

}
```

You could call:

```
val adapter = NavDrawerItemAdapter(NavDrawerItemAdapter.ItemSelectedListener {
    it // is an adapter!
})
```

That is because you're trying to reference something that has not been created yet.

Another option would be to use a setter for the listener if it were available.